# Correct way to wait for sql i/o to complete

Tags: netty

Does anyone have a simple code example showing how netty 3.2.7
should correctly handle an sql query in the following scenario:

The calling method passes the message to the server messageReceived
method. The messageRecieved method does the sql query and gets the
result. The calling method should not continue processing until it
gets the result of the sql query.

In particular, an example of the way that netty waits for the
i/o (sql query) to complete would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an ExecutionHandler in front of your handler that does the sql query. Thats it...

Otherwise you will block your worker-thread

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, it does not answer the point about
how netty correctly waits for the result from the sql and
returns it to the calling method.

Otherwise the calling method continues before it has the result from
the sql (and it needs the result to correctly progress).

Comment: I think it answer the question as the other "handlers" behind your handler that does call the sql will only execute after the one with the sql code has complete. So I think its what you want, or did I miss-understood it ?

Check out: http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/execution/ExecutionHandler.html

Answer (score 0):

Norman thanks for the extra information. This I think this could solve the issue, but it involves adding an extra handler which is not really required and would be added purely to ensure that the sql query has completed (with no functionality).

I looked for a "more standard" way and found the link
"http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelFuture.html" which says "Various methods are provided to let you check if the I/O operation has been completed, wait for the completion, and retrieve the result of the I/O operation. It also allows you to add ChannelFutureListeners so you can get notified when the I/O operation is completed. ...."

It also says Prefer addListener(ChannelFutureListener) to await() but I don't know how to implement this.
If anyone knows how to implement this to wait for the result of an i/o sql query to complete it would be very useful.

To solve the issue in the sendMessage method I used

```
lastWriteFuture = connector.write(message);
if (lastWriteFuture != null) {
      lastWriteFuture.awaitUninterruptibly();
}
```

This works - it waits for the sql query to complete and then retuns to the caller.

Comment: Ah yeah this works.. I thought you want to wait for the sql to be complete from within the io thread. In the io thread you can't call await*() as it will deadlock.